# Why isn't the first line not aligning properly in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2008

I am trying to type a document but I find that on some pages on the right hand side it doesn't align. It is part of a sentence but just doesn't auto align to be justified.

```
It would look like this
it would look  like  this
it would  look  like this
```

I have tried adding spaces, playing with margins I just can't work it out. Help!!

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Please clarify what you are attempting to do.

Comment: A screenshot of the symptoms would also be nice... :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need just to format your text by `justify low` as drop-down menu in paragraph section.